# Can I use the standard http.get library to access an API served on a GCP compute instance using the internal IP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-workflows, google-compute-api

I have a GCP Workflows accessing an API served on a GCP Compute Instance using the public IP and it is working fine.

Now I want to use the same Workflows but accessing by private IP and I get a ConnectionError.

Is there any limitation of the GCP Workflows to access by private IP to the GCP Compute Instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workflows are not part of your VPC, therefore no access is possible to private IP addresses. Workflows do not yet support [VPC access connectors](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access), which would allow for VPC access.